# NodeJS setImmediate loop: Is only one setImmediate callback executed per iteration of the event loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, event-loop, setimmediate

```js
function loop() {
  // Anything you want to run in a loop can be here

  setImmediate(loop);
}

loop();
```

In this case, a `setImmediate` callback is calling another `setImmediate` whose callback is eventually to the queue (of the "Check" phase). Thus `loop()` runs repeatedly

Does only one `setImmediate` callback run per iteration of the event loop? i.e. does `loop()` only run once per iteration of the event loop?

I often hear that `setImmediate` is used to run a callback on the next "tick" or iteration of the event loop

However, the official Node documentation on the event loop (https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/) says:

*"generally, when the event loop enters a given phase, it will perform any operations specific to that phase, then execute callbacks in that phase's queue until the queue has been exhausted or the maximum number of callbacks has executed."*

This makes me think that potentially multiple `setImmediate` callbacks are run per iteration of the event loop. If this is the case, how can we know how many `setImmediate` callbacks are executed per "tick"?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: There are 2 cases here: multiple callbacks scheduled in the same execution (`setImmediate(cb1); setImmediate(cb2)`)  and the recursive case that you expose `setImmediate(() => { cb1(); setImmediate(cb2); })`. The first case will apparently schedule both `cb1` and `cb2` in the same frame (in node <=10 it wouldn't even let a Promise callback execute in-between). The second case will execute each callback in its own frame letting the other phases do their own stuff in-between.

Comment: Thank you, Kaiido, great points. I think you're definitely right

Answer (score 1):

Considering loop terminates for a certain condition. The `setImmediate()` callback will call every time `loop`'s execution ends. As the [doc](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/#setimmediate-vs-settimeout):

> `setImmediate()` is designed to execute a script once the current poll
> phase completes.

In simple terms, its a callback for the function that you pass, which will execute for every time at the of it's execution.

Consider the following example, you will observe that in the output `currentCount` value increments when the function ends or as the doc says, at every 'tick'.

```js
const count = 5;
let currentCount = 0;
const array = [];

function loop() {
  console.log('start', currentCount);
  let a = setImmediate((...args) => {
    if (currentCount == count) {
      array.forEach((b) => clearImmediate(b));
    } else {
      console.log(...args, currentCount);
      setTimeout(loop, 1000);
    }
  }, 'data');
  currentCount++;
  array.push(a);
  console.log('end', currentCount);
}

loop();
```

Output:

```
❯ node index.js
start 0
end 1
data 1
start 1
end 2
data 2
start 2
end 3
data 3
start 3
end 4
data 4
start 4
end 5
```

Comment: Thank you, shrys. I want to upvote you for taking the time to help, though I'm not high enough reputation yet to do so. However, I'm also having difficulty following your code example, and I think including a `setTimeout()` seems to complicate this as we now need to consider another phase of the event loop (i.e. the "Timers" phase)

Comment: Hey @regna, the code would proceed execute the same steps with or without `setTimeout`. My intention was to show the output with a timeout.

Comment: Would encourage you to play around with the [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-3zpfhr?file=index.js) as well

Answer (score 0):

I believe that for the `setImmediate` loop code snippet in the original question that there is only one `setImmediate` callback per iteration of the event loop

I ran an example below that helped resolve this in my mind and hope this is correct:

```js
function loop() {
    console.log('setImmediate loop');

    setImmediate(loop);
}

loop();

setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('setTimeout');

    process.exit();
}, 3); // You can adjust the timeout duration for more setImmediate callbacks before setTimeout's callback is called
```

```bash
# Output
setImmediate loop
setImmediate loop
setImmediate loop
setImmediate loop
setImmediate loop
setImmediate loop
setImmediate loop
setImmediate loop
setImmediate loop
setImmediate loop
setTimeout
```

This seems to suggest that only one (or at least not many) `setImmediate` callback runs per tick of the event loop. Otherwise, if the `setImmediate` loop was starving the event loop (with countless `setImmediate` callbacks running per tick of the event loop), `setTimeout`'s callback would be blocked. I doubt that 10 callbacks is the hard limit or *"maximum number of callbacks"* mentioned in the [official Node documentation](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/):

*"generally, when the event loop enters a given phase, it will perform any operations specific to that phase, then execute callbacks in that phase's queue until the queue has been exhausted or the maximum number of callbacks has executed."*

Moreover, by adjusting the `setTimeout` duration, you can vary the number of `setImmediate loop` console logs before the `setTimeout` callback. This confirms that a hard limit or maximum number of callbacks is not being reached

In summary, it seems that `setImmediate()`'s called during the "Poll" phase won't have their callbacks run until subsequent event loop ticks. In contrast, immediately resolved promises or `process.nextTick()`'s called while the microtask or nextTick queue is being processed will have their callbacks run before proceeding to the next stage of the event loop